# RequestError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com

Tags: node.js, proxy, yarnpkg, yeoman, theia

am trying to launch a theia extension using `yeoman` from the `PowerShell` but I think am facing a `Proxy issue` as I am using my company's network

```
yo theia-extension
```

results in

[image]

by the way I have defined this

```
git config --global http://login:password@company's_domain:port(8080)
```

Comment: This is an issue with your network connection. As we don't know how you configured it, it's quite hard to help ...

Comment: @derpirscher I haven't configure anything but the http-proxy, https-proxy and GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue. I made a mistake by installing `yarn` multiple times, first with `scoop` then with `npm`. So, even after setting the `Proxy` correctly, when executing the command, it will be confused between the two versions.
That's what I have understood.

---

By the way, here's how to set `yarn` behind `proxy`:

```
yarn config set YARN_HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@host:port    //most likely 8080
yarn config set YARN_HTTP_PROXY=http://http://username:password@host:port   //host/domaine url
```